# how soon can return to austria to be with my family after being here 90 days

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, austria, 90-180-visa-rules

Can I return to Austria in a few days to be with my daughter. I am a US citizen and have 2 yr leave to remain visa visa. My daughter needs me here in Austria.

---

May I just say that my 2 year leave to remain visa is for the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stay in the Schengen area for a maximum of 90 days in any 180 (the 90/180 rule<sup>1</sup>). If you've already been in the area for 90 days you must stay away for 90 days before you return.

Be aware that if you return after 90 days, planning to stay for another 90 days, sooner or later you will be denied entry as it will appear that you are trying to live in the Schengen area through repeated visits.

There is no way to extend your stay under the 90/180 rule. If you wish to stay longer you must apply for a [national visa D](https://www.bmeia.gv.at/en/travel-stay/entry-and-residence-in-austria/entry-and-visa/visa-d/) that will permit a stay of up to six months. More than that will require a residence permit.

<sup>1</sup>Codified in [Regulation (EU) 610/2013](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2013:182:0001:0018:EN:PDF)

Comment: Does it matter that my daughter is under 21 and has hidden disabilities? She would be travelling with me.

Comment: She is an EU citizen

Comment: @evieschiller No

Comment: @evieschiller, the citizenship connection may matter if and when you apply for an Austrian long-stay visa. Questions about that as best asked on Expatriates Stack Exchange.